# Calling a html file from a Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a file called `index.html` which has been placed directly inside `WebContent`  and all the script files are in the right place as well.

The servlet looks like this:

```
public class CreateService extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public CreateService() {
      super();
   }

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
         doPost(request,response);
   }

   //calling html file instead of jsp 
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {

         String gisuniqkey=request.getParameter("gisuniqkey");
         RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = 
             getServletConfig().getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
         reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);       
   }
}
```

When I try to load the url in the server says that the resource could not be found.This is the error that I get:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false],     
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false],   
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false],   
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false],  
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false],   
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false],   
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property  
'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TestProject' did not find a matching property.
PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8180"]
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1481 ms
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8180"]
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2767 ms
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
.:
assets               images        META-INF             test.jsp
CreateScenario.jsp   index.html    ms.jsp               UpdateScenario.jsp
cs.jsp               index.jsp     multipleDisplay.jsp  WEB-INF
css                  js            objtype.json
DisplayScenario.jsp  JsonData      Scenario.json
EditScenario.jsp     jsonscenario  scripts

./scripts:
gmaps_createScenario.js  gmaps_drawPolygon.js  info.js  maploader.js
gmaps_drawLine.js        gmaps_events.js       lib
gmaps_drawMarker.js      gmaps.js              main.js

./scripts/lib:
backbone.min.js  jquery.min.js  plugins  require.js  underscore.min.js

./scripts/lib/plugins:
async.js   font.js  image.js  mdown.js  propertyParser.js
depend.js  goog.js  json.js   noext.js
```

This is the [web.xml file in a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kP4rRAQQ)

This was in `MainService`,I believe that this redirects to `CreateService`:

```
 RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/CreateService");
        reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

This throws the following error when I try and call the url:

```
 Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the    
 server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

Comment: can you post the file structure of your application?

Comment: Also I think the redirection URL should be "index.html" and not "/index.html"

Comment: I am still not seeing the resource,the url I was told to call `http://localhost:8180/GisProject/MainService?scenario=C&operation=1`

Comment: What's the absolute URL to get `scripts/main.js`? Can you download it? And what about all those warnings?

Comment: Hmm your log doesn't say anything about index.html cannot be found. Can you post your web.xml? Does the url GisProject/MainService map to CreateService?

Comment: @Alvin posted the `web.xml` as a pastebin

Comment: okay.. try calling http://localhost:8180/GisProject/CreateService and see what you get.

Comment: You're doing a FORWARD not a REDIRECT.  Can you really forward to a .html?  I've never tried, but it makes no sense, since the difference between forward and redirect is that forward preserves the request parameters and attributes (which .html can't do anything with). You might need to change it to a .jsp or change it to `response.sendRedirect("index.html"); return;`

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to call `http://localhost:8180/GisProject/MainService?` which will invokde `MainService` class according to your `web.xml`. However what you show here is `CreateService` which will get invoked if you call `http://localhost:8180/GisProject/CreateService`.

If what you want is to display `index.html` when calling `http://localhost:8180/GisProject/MainService` then you have to move the implementation to `MainService` class.